# Python: last element of tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I would isolate the last element of a tuple like

```
a = (3,5,5)
last = a[-1]
```

but the problem is that i have a pice ok code like this

```
if var == last:
  do something
```

and it takes the first `5` and not the second, how can i do to take the last one?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the question? What is `var` ? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: How do you know which 5 it is taking? They both look the same to me. :-P

Comment: var is a variable in this case is 5

Comment: Show your loop/code to allow a better understanding of your question.

Comment: they are not the same, one is in the last position and the other no, the if became true with the first 5 i would that it will be true only for the last 5

Comment: Again, what is the *problem* you have? What you posted is your *attempt* to solve the problem!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are trying to do is impossible. Those two fives are exactly the same.

However, when iterating over the tuple you can check if you reached the last element like this:

```
a = (3, 5, 5)
for i, var in enumerate(a):
    if i == len(a) - 1:
        print 'last element:'
    print var
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: a = (3, 5, 5)
In [2]: for i, var in enumerate(a):
   ...:     if i == len(a) - 1:
   ...:         print 'last element:'
   ...:     print var
   ...:
3
5
last element:
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack tuples like this:

```py
t = (3, 5, 5)
*_, last = t
assert last == 5
```